# Displaying images horizontally or 4images per row in php

Tags: php, html, css

```html
<?php 
                                    $query1=mysqli_query($db_con,"select * from image_tb");
                                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
                                 ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="block-content collapse in">
                                <div class="row-fluid padd-bottom">
                                  <div class="span3">
                                      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $row['img_location'];?> "  alt="260x180" style="width: 260px; height: 180px;">
                                      </a>
                                  </div>
                                  
                                  
                                  <?php
                                        }
                                    ?>
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGHal.png)[I need to display the images horizontally But all the images are displaying vertically.]

[here's the image vertically displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGHal.png)

[it should be display like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfWsK.png)

Comment: This not even a question. We wont do your work for you. Show us what attempts you have made so far. Tip - Use CSS for styling.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not with the code, but the style, right?

on CSS:

```
img {
  float: left;
}
```